# SP2010 Update the permissions of a sharepoint group on a list

Tags: 2010, development

I have a list (mylist) which inherits custom groups with custom permission levels from the site the list is located in. 
Now I would like to change the custom permission of only one of the groups (groupToChange) and only for this specific list (mylist).

I wonder if I would get there ok with the below code:

```
SPList mylist = web.Lists["MyList"];<br> 
SPGroupCollection spgc = SharePointConfiguration.Site.SiteGroups;<br>
SPGroup group = spgc[groupToChange];<br>
SPRoleAssignment roleAssignment = new SPRoleAssignment((SPPrincipal)group);<br> 
mylist.Item.BreakRoleInheritance(true);<br> 
roleAssignment.RoleDefinitionBindings.Add(SharePointConfiguration.Site.RoleDefinitions["New Permission Level"]);<br>

mylist.Item.RoleAssignments.Add(roleAssignment);
mylist.Update();
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the end I solved this issue like this:

using (SPWeb web = properties.GetWeb()) { string[] grpNames = new string[3] { "Administrators", "Secretaries", "Visitors" };             string[] grpPermissions = new string[3] { "Administrator Permission", "Lists Secretary Permission", "Visitor Permission" };              SPList list = web.Lists["MyList"];              list.BreakRoleInheritance(false);             while (list.RoleAssignments.Count > 0)             {                 list.RoleAssignments.Remove(0);             }              for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++)             {                 SPGroup Lgroup = web.SiteGroups[grpNames[i]];                 SPRoleAssignment roleassignment_group = new SPRoleAssignment(Lgroup);                 roleassignment_group.RoleDefinitionBindings.Add(web.RoleDefinitions[grpPermissions[i]]);                 list.RoleAssignments.Add(roleassignment_group);                 list.Update();             }          }